# How can I create a math formula text view with LaTeX in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to Swift programing and wish to create an app with SwiftUI. This is what I wish to achieve:

[image: Desired result]

that is, a text field that has real-time syntax highlighting for `LaTeX`, and then the content of which is being rendered by `mathjax` and shown in a web view.

I did some search on this site and on GitHub, only to find related codes are mostly in Objective-C or Swift 4.x (such as [this](https://github.com/appcoda/JavaScriptCoreDemo)), and none of them has interface made with SwiftUI. However, during my research I found one approach that might work. It seems that with the [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) framework one may able to use of [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org) to make syntax highlighting (like what [Highlightr](https://github.com/raspu/Highlightr) done there, but its codes are very complex). I'm convinced by this approach because if one can use `highlight.js` to achieve code highlighting, then in a similar way one should be able to use other JavaScripts like `mathjax.js` to achieve other features.

Unfortunately, since I'm new to Swift and hence SwiftUI, I have no idea where to begin with. Could anyone kindly offer me some hints? (Any help is welcome, not necessarily use `JavaScriptCore`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution using a great framework, [RichTextView](https://github.com/tophat/RichTextView):

```
import RichTextView

struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State var string : String = "In physics, the mass-energy equivalence is stated by the equation [math]$E=mc^2$[/math], discovered in 1905 by Albert Einstein."
    
    var body : some View {
        TextField("Test", text: $string)
            .padding(.vertical, 32)
            .border(Color.red)
        
        TextView(string: $string)
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    }
}


struct TextView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var string : String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> RichTextView {
        let richTextView = RichTextView(
            input: string,
            latexParser: LatexParser(),
            font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize),
            textColor: UIColor.black,
            frame: CGRect.zero,
            completion: nil
        )
        
        return richTextView
        
    }

   func updateUIView(_ uiView: RichTextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.update(
            input: string,
            latexParser: LatexParser(),
            font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize),
            textColor: UIColor.black,
            completion: nil
        )
   }
}
```

[image]

You always have to start with [math] and end with [/math] but can use default Latex. More information on their documentation.

[image]

Comment: May I ask how to add `RichTextView` into my project? I get this error: `https://github.com/tophat/RichTextView has no Package.swift manifest`.

Comment: I installed it with Podfile

Answer (score 2):

Here is my current solution, it uses the [CodeViewer](https://github.com/dwarvesf/CodeViewer) package for code highlighting, and `mathjax.js` to render maths.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CodeViewer

struct LaTeXView: View {
    @State private var placeholderString: String = "Insert here"
    @State private var inputText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //MARK: Code editor
            CodeViewer(
                content: $inputText,
                mode: .latex,
                darkTheme: .solarized_dark,
                lightTheme: .solarized_light,
                isReadOnly: false,
                fontSize: 50
            )
            
            //MARK: for rendering math
            HTMLStringView(htmlContent: """
                <html>
                <head>
                  <meta charset="utf-8">
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
                  <title>MathJax example</title>
                  <script>MathJax = {
                        tex:{
                                inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
                                tags: 'ams'
                            },
                        svg:{
                                fontCache: 'global'
                            }
                        };
                  </script>
                  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
                  <script id="MathJax-script" async
                          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
                  </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                <p>
                \(inputText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n\n", with: "<br>"))
                </p>
                </body>
                </html>
                """
            )
        }
    }
}

struct LaTeXView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LaTeXView()
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Result]